# How to make the mouse hover over a piece of text with Protractor

Tags: protractor, mouse

I want to make the mouse hove over a piece of text in Protractor, tried following code:

```
         browser.actions()
        .mouseDown($(".bln_Phrases"))
        .mouseMove($(".bln_Phrases"),{x: 700, y: 436})
        .perform();
```

but I got error message from log of protractor: "**Failed: HTTP method not allowed**". please advise how can I make it work? Is there any module should be imported? 
This is the HTML which I would like to hover:

```
<span id="5746d22a9a88b65686da14819be1ba04" class="bln_Phrases">1000 </span>
```

thanks.

Comment: Share the `html` of the text you wish to hover

Comment: the html is added into my original question above, I also changed my typo on class locator, please advise, thanks.

Comment: Are you testing with Firefox?

Comment: Yes， with Firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.actions().mouseMove($(".baselinePhrasesClass").perform();
```

Comment: I tried this way, but get the same error, thank you.